# How do I redraw and reorganise the elements within an Isotope container upon reordering the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

As per [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjcd/8NvMk/), I create an [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) container which contains each of my elements, upon clicking one of the links (bottom left) I'd like to reorder the elements, pulling the matched elements to the left of my container.

I do this by removing them from the DOM and shifting them to the top of the containing div. If you check your browser's console you'll see that this happens successfully, but the following call to Isotope (to redraw) fires the callback, but doesn't seem to trigger the actual redraw. Not entirely sure why this is the case, is anyone able to explain?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved it:

```
$('#products').isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope( { sortBy: 'original-order' } );
```

or just:

```
$('#products').isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope();
```

Still not sure why reLayout doesn't trigger this behaviour though.

Comment: Thanks.
Both options reload all items successful, However with the first one this reload properly after any isotope('appended', items).

Answer (score 1):

After adding new items to your grid, you need to add them to Isotope, but if you add them directly (i.e., if item contains an image and is still not loaded) then the layout will be not be correct.

You need to use [`imageLoaded`](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout.html#imagesloaded) like this:

```
var $items = $(response).find('.grid-item');
$container.append($items);                    //add items to grid
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.isotope( 'appended', $items );   //add items to isotope after images are loaded
});
```